# Установка Qt5 и Qt Creator 2.6.1 в Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, я скачай с сайта Qt инсталлер Qt5 + Qt Creator 2.6.1, установил его так:

```
chmod +x qt5.run
sudo ./qt5.run
```

Но при попытках запустить Qt Creator у меня выскакивало много ошибок Premission denied. Пришлось удалить.
На форумах читал, что нужно устанавливать из репозиториев, но там старая версия.
Скажите пожалуйста, как можно установить Qt5 и Qt Creator 2.6.1?

Comment: есть подозрение что с помощью sudo ./qt5.run Вы установили его с доступом к нему только суперюзера, что будет если запустить sudo ./QtCreator или то-то типа (не помню как именно там обзывается скрипт на запуск)?

Comment: запустил вот так:

    cd /opt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin
    sudo ./qtcreator.sh

Запускалось долго, но запустилось нормально

Comment: Я читал, что QT5 ещё очень сырой, и QtCreator вроде только недавно нормально скомпилировали (а может и нет). Если нет такого задания, что использовать именно 5 QT, то лучше писать на 4.8 и не тревожиться. Тем более, что он есть в пакетах.

Comment: Есть такое дело, а QTComponents, которые вроде как должны быть основным способом разработки под настольные системы, так и вовсе падали при движении мышки, но думаю здесь просто не те права доступа. Советую попробовать сменить хозяина дирректории через chown

Comment: @aknew, не подскажете, как такое провернуть?

Comment: для начала запустите  ls -l в папке с  QtCreator и посмотрите, кто там указан в качестве хозяина (owner) фаила, если root, то поробуйте это сменить через sudo chown -R YouUser ./ , -R могу ошибаться - не помню какой там ключ, а проверить сейчас не могу. Можно еще конечно через chmod поменять правадоступа, но это как-то уже не хорошо будет

Comment: @aknew непомогло :(
тогда поставлю 4.8, думаю, ничем не хуже, вот только не подскажете как?

Comment: 4.8 вроде в репозитории был

Comment: @aknew, а можно ли как-нибудь обновить qtcreator с 2.5.2 до более новой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня комменты закончились. Более новый можно, но брать его надо оттуда же откуда 5.0 и устанавливать так же, а значит у вас он скорее всего не заведется. Почему -не знаю, я ставил на убунту qt-бинарники с их сайта и проблем у меня не было, скорее всего есть что-то, что вы (и я при ответе) не учли

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я себе всё-таки поставил 4.8. Он тоже, вроде, не плох :)